# What is a sex-biased gene?

Tags: evolution, genetics, natural-selection, sexual-selection, definitions

How do you define a male-biased gene and a female-biased gene as they are found in the abstract of [this article](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/20059540).

Comment: perhaps by strong difference in expression between two sexes.

Comment: WYSIWYG yes, that's what I was thinking too. Let's wait and see if someone can make sure of this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the linked paper, the authors discuss this as sex-based gene expression that evolved by sex-specific selection. The expression is not limited to one sex (which are sex-limited genes). Sex-biased genes are expressed by both sexes, but differently between sexes.